# Default app/widget background was black, but now is white?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an old Android project and it always worked fine everywhere. So now I bought a new computer, installed the latest Android Studio and launched it and .... the background color is white instead of black!

This is a big problem because in many places across the app I hard-coded white text and now it doesn't show. Hard-coding to black obviously will cause it to stop working in older devices with black background. I tried adding a res/values/colors.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <drawable name="screen_background_holo_light">#ff000000</drawable>
  <drawable name="screen_background_holo_dark">#ff000000</drawable>
  <color name="background_holo_dark">#ff000000</color>
   <color name="background_holo_light">#ff000000</color>
  <color name="black">#000000</color>
```

and adding a styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/black</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I tried installing the oldest possible emulator (API version 24) instead of the default emulator for API 30.

Nothing made any difference.

I don't set the background color anywhere in my app, it was just the default one.... I don't want to support white/dark themes or whatever (unless that's the only way to fix this)

Any ideas? I haven't found anything googling which is really puzzling...

thanks,

[image]

My Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.felipe.truedemocracy"
  android:versionCode="12"
  android:versionName="1.0.12">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<supports-screens
  android:smallScreens="true"
  android:normalScreens="true"
  android:largeScreens="true"
  android:anyDensity="true" />
<!-- was 14 -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v7.app.CoreComponentFactory"
    tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
    android:largeHeap="true">
    <activity android:name="com.felipe.truedemocracy.TrueDemocracyGamesLauncher"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.felipe.truedemocracy.ui.democracy.TrueDemocracyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name_td"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.felipe.truedemocracy.ui.worldorder.TrueWorldOrderActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name_two"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.felipe.truedemocracy.ui.trueciv.TrueCivActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name_civ"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- AdMob -->
.....
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you add your styles.xml

Comment: @user14678216

My project does not have a styles.xml, it never had such a file. It is a very old project, from before Android Studio even existed.... I tried adding one:

    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        </style>
    </resources>`

but  now it won't build:

   ` resource style/Theme.AppCompat (aka 
    com.felipe.truedemocracy:style/Theme.AppCompat) not found.`

Comment: Does it have a gradle and manifest file?

Comment: @user14678216 ok, now I managed to build it, but there was no change in the background with the styles.xml which I posted above.

Yes, the project uses gradle and of course it has a manifest (is it even possible to have an Android app in Google Play without it? My app is in Google Play). I had to do the following:  

1> upgrade classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4' to 4.0.1  
2>  create a gradle.properties file with android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true  
3>  added to manifest file: android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v7.app.CoreComponentFactory"

Comment: but like I said, this basically only allowed me to build the project with a styles.xml, the background is still white instead of black. Maybe I should downgrade to Android SDK simply. I am using Android Studio by the way.. I will add the manifast in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `styles.xml` to change the background color:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
```

So you end up with something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    //...
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
</style>
```

Alternatively I see that the version of the app on Google Play is in the Dark Holo theme which you can set by setting the parent theme to `parent="android:Theme.Holo"`

Or add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"` to the manifest.

Comment: None of the above worked, but lead by your tips I found an answer, adding android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/> to the application part of the manifest worked! if you change your answer I can set it as accepted.

Comment: Done :-) I have added it.